# Storing cos and sin into a vector and getting weird values

Tags: c++, floating-point

My code

```
double to_radians(double theta)
{
    return (M_PI * theta) / 180.0;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> points;
    for (double theta = 0.0; theta <= 360.0; theta += 30.0)
    {
        points.push_back(std::make_pair(std::cos(to_radians(theta)), std::sin(to_radians(theta))));
    }
    for (auto point : points)
        std::cout << point.first << " " << point.second << "\n";
}
```

Output I expect

```
1 0
0.866025 0.5
0.5 0.866025
0 1
-0.5 0.866025
-0.866025 0.5
-1 0
-0.866025 -0.5
-0.5 -0.866025
0 -1
0.5 -0.866025
0.866025 -0.5
1 0
```

Output I get:

```
1 0
0.866025 0.5
0.5 0.866025
6.12303e-17 1
-0.5 0.866025
-0.866025 0.5
-1 1.22461e-16
-0.866025 -0.5
-0.5 -0.866025
-1.83691e-16 -1
0.5 -0.866025
0.866025 -0.5
1 -2.44921e-16
```

As you can see I am getting these strange values instead of zero. Can somebody explain why this is happening?

Comment: I think that your data is correct, `6.12303e-17` is essentially `0`. (It is 6 times ten to the - 17th power, which is 0.000000000000000006)

Comment: In addition to the answers provided, [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) is a helpful read.

Comment: You may want to check whether your platform offers (as an extension beyond the current C++ standard) the functions `sinpi()` and `cospi()`. If so, you should get more accurate results by calling `sinpi(theta/180.0)` and `cospi(theta/180.0)`. [CRlibm](http://lipforge.ens-lyon.fr/www/crlibm/) is one library that offers these functions.

Answer (score 10):

`6.12303e-17`, to take an example, represents the value 6.12303*10<sup>-17</sup>, or 0.00000000000000000612303.

The reason you obtain this value as result is that you did not apply `cos` to π/2, which is not representable as a `double` anyway (it's irrational). The `cos` function was applied to a `double` close to π/2, obtained by multiplying 90 by `M_PI` and dividing by 180. Since the argument is not π/2, the result does not have to be 0. In fact, since floating-point numbers are more dense near zero, it is extremely unlikely for any floating-point format that applying a correctly rounded `cos` to any floating-point number produces exactly zero as result.

In fact, since the derivative of `cos` in π/2 is -1, the value obtained for the expression `cos(M_PI/2.0)` is a close approximation of the difference between `M_PI/2` and π/2. That difference is indeed of the order of d*10<sup>-17</sup>, since the double-precision IEEE 754 format can only represent the first 16 or so first decimal digits of an arbitrary number.

---

Note that the same argument applies to obtaining `0.5` as the result of `cos(M_PI/3.0)`, or even `-1.0` as the result of `cos(M_PI)`. The difference is that there are many floating-point numbers, some very small, around 0, and these can represent very precisely the intended non-zero result. In comparison, `0.5` and `-1.0` have only a few neighbors, and for inputs close enough to π/3 and π, the numbers `0.5` and `-1.0` end up being returned as the nearest representable double-precision value to the respective mathematical result (which isn't 1/2 or -1, since the input is not π/3 or π).

The simplest solution to your problem would be to use hypothetical functions `cosdeg` and `sindeg` that would compute directly the cosine and sine of angles in degrees. Since 60 and 90 are representable exactly as double-precision floating-point numbers, these functions would have no excuse not to return 0.5 or 0.0 (also exactly representable as double-precision floating-point numbers). I asked [a question in relation to these functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104904/how-to-compute-correctly-rounded-trigonometric-functions-in-degrees) earlier but no-one pointed to any already available implementation.

The functions `sinpi` and `cospi` pointed out by njuffa are often available, and they allow to compute the sine and cosine or π/2, π/4 or even 7.5*π, but not of π/3, since the number 1/3 they would have to be applied to is not representable exactly in binary floating-point.

Answer (score 0):

It's a floating point rounding error. Trig functions are implemented as mathematical series that are approximated on the computational level which causes for numbers very close to zero for example `6.12303e-17` rather than the expected `0`.

Comment: A correctly rounded double-precision `cos` or `sin` does not produce 0 for any non-zero argument. The details of the implementation have nothing to do with it.

Comment: That's absolutely true. Your answer explaining how pi/2 is a double close to the irrational number is a better and more succinct answer. Thanks for the comment.